# How can I visualize the waveform in react from the audio generated in ros?

Tags: reactjs, audio, ros, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am new to ROS. I know there are libraries in React where I can capture the audio from the microphone and also visualize it. But is it possible that I capture the microphone input on ROS and show the waveform visualization in react? Any leads would be appreciated. TIA

Update: I was able to connect ros and react with react-ros library and I am also able to get the audio signal in array format. But I am able to replicate the same into audio waveform. I tried webaudio api for the same, but I am able to replicate that into a wave. Also, my audio is continuous streaming from ros and react should be able to capture the signals and convert to waveform simultaneously and update. Below is the code snippet I tried, but I am getting a square wave and not a continuous sine wave. Please help.

```
//EchoTopic.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useROS } from 'react-ros'

var listener = null;
let audioData = [];

function EchoTopic() {
const { createListener, topics } = useROS();
const [topic, setTopic] = useState('/');

useEffect(() => {
handleTopic(topic);
});
const unsubscribe = () => {
if (listener) {
listener.unsubscribe();
}
}
const handleTopic = (topicInput) => {
if (topic !== topicInput) {
setTopic(topicInput);
unsubscribe();
return;
}
unsubscribe();
listener = null;
for (var i in topics) {
if (topics[i].path === topicInput) {
listener = createListener(topics[i].path,
topics[i].msgType);
break;
}
}
if (listener) {
console.log("subscribing to messages...");
listener.subscribe(handleMsg);
} else {
console.log("Topic '" + topic + "' not found...make sure to input the full topic path - including the leading '/'");
}
}
const handleMsg = (msg) => {
console.log(msg);
audioData =[...msg_signals_vect];
}
return (
<div>
<b>Topic to echo:  </b><input name="topicInput" defaultValue={topic} onChange={event => handleTopic(event.target.value)} />  <br />
<AudioVisualiser audioData = {audioData}/>
</div>
);
}
export default EchoTopic;


//AudioVisualiser.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AudioVisualiser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    const { audioData } = this.props;
    const canvas = this.canvas.current;
    const height = canvas.height;
    const width = canvas.width;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let x = 0;
    const sliceWidth = (width * 1.0) / audioData.length;

    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, height / 2);
    for (const item of audioData) {
      const y = (item / 255.0) * height;
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      x += sliceWidth;
    }
    context.lineTo(x, height / 2);
    context.stroke();
  }

  render() {
    return <canvas width="300" height="300" ref={this.canvas} />;
  }
}

export default AudioVisualiser;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, this description is to vague to help you though imho. I assume you use `python` SDK for ROS, but how do you plan to transfer the data to the FE (React app)?  By default a FE app has no access to file system so you have to send your data through something REST / gRPC / something else. The other option is to upload the data somewhere (S3, Blob Storage, Google Drive,,,) and fetch it in FE.

Comment: Yes, I will be using FastAPI to send the data. I want to live stream the audio, rather than storing it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The error code in the line where audio data is extracted from the ROS message
On your code, it was assumed that the audio data is stored in a field called `msg_signals_vect`.

To fix this error, replace this line. for example: from `audioData = [...msg_signals_vect];` to `audioData = [...msg.signals_vect];`

Make sure to replace `audioData` with the correct field name based on your ROS message structure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have changed the above line of code. But I am still unable to visualize this code in the form of a sine wave. Could you please help me?